# Extract two lines following a line with a specific value

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file and I would like to extract the two lines of data following a line containing only "Name" as a value.

> Name
>
> 032
>
> Express intent to engage in diplomatic cooperation (such as policy
>
> support)
>
> Description
>
> Name
>
> 033
>
> Express intent to provide material aid, not speciﬁed below
>
> Description

So, the output from above would be a file that has:

> 032 Express intent to engage in diplomatic cooperation (such as policy support)
>
> 033 Express intent to provide material aid, not specified below

Comment: @don_crissti hopefully that does the trick

Comment: Your sample input appears to be double-spaced, is that accurate?

Comment: Anyway, look at the `-A` option to `grep`.

Comment: Use the `{ }` code markup for sample input/output, not quotation.

Comment: @don_crissti I've imagined the scenario thusly and concluded it makes sense to _me_

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip, that's _helpful_ I'll do that now

Comment: @nacc Is there really a line break between `support` and policy`? If so, it needs to read 3 lines after `Name`. But the second part of the sample only has 2 lines after `Name`. How is it supposed to know when to stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/Name/ { readline; num=$0; readline; print num, $0; }' < inputfile
```

`readline` reads the next line of the input into `$0`. So when `Name` is matched, it reads the next line, puts it into the `num` variable, then reads the second line, and then prints `num` and that line together on one line.